# how to send message to mailing list with apache mail?

Tags: java, email, javafx

I am working on an application to send emails with javafx and apache mail commons, but it throws and error when i try to send the message.

```
Caused by: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in 
string `` ''
at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.createInternetAddress(Email.java:1949)
... 59 more
```

Anyways i noticed when i initialize the array of strings with my recipients it sends it correctly, but if i take them from the database it throws the error i wrote above.

**The way it works.**

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
...
String[] emails = {"email1@domain.com", "email2@domain.com"}
email.addTo(emails);
```

**The way it doesn't work**

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
...
String[] emails = model.getEmailsBy(campaignName); //Returns a string[]
email.addTo(emails);
```

**Important**: model.getEmailsBy(campaignName); is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there must be at least one blank or invalid email in the list of model.getEmailsBy(campaignName); and this is the reason of 
 Illegal address in 
string `` ''.